# Conditional binding from view model?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have several listviews with two collumns like.
I am building a stats application for another application.
Each row should have two columns. 
(Name,Sum) or (Name,Count)
The problem is that the model has three(Name,Sum,Count).And i want to have a general switch to determine which column should be shown at all 6 listviews. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Not sure this deserved a downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a style for the ListView and only add the columns that you want depending on a property that shows which view you're after.

CountSumSwitch is a boolean dependency property that I have in MainWindow, you switch it to true to display the counts in all listviews and false to display the sum in all listviews.

```
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- This binding needs to point to some global propery that you'll change to switch views.-->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CountSumSwitch}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="View">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Count" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Count}" />
                        </GridView>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CountSumSwitch}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="View">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Sum" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Sum}" />
                        </GridView>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Edit:

To show this in action I'll add an example, it shows a listview bound to a collection with a checkbox to toggle the columns that are used. Create a new WPF application, replace the MainWindow class with this

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public bool CountSumSwitch
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(CountSumSwitchProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CountSumSwitchProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CountSumSwitchProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CountSumSwitch", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));


        public List<TheItem> ITems
        {
            get { return (List<TheItem>)GetValue(ITemsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ITemsProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ITemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ITems", typeof(List<TheItem>), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Random rnd = new Random();

            ITems = new List<TheItem>(new TheItem[]
            {
                new TheItem () { Name = "Item 1", Count = rnd.Next(100), Sum = rnd.Next (100)}, 
                new TheItem () { Name = "Item 2", Count = rnd.Next(100), Sum = rnd.Next (100)}, 
                new TheItem () { Name = "Item 3", Count = rnd.Next(100), Sum = rnd.Next (100)}, 
                new TheItem () { Name = "Item 4", Count = rnd.Next(100), Sum = rnd.Next (100)}, 
                new TheItem () { Name = "Item 5", Count = rnd.Next(100), Sum = rnd.Next (100)}, 
                new TheItem () { Name = "Item 6", Count = rnd.Next(100), Sum = rnd.Next (100)}, 
                new TheItem () { Name = "Item 7", Count = rnd.Next(100), Sum = rnd.Next (100)}, 
                new TheItem () { Name = "Item 8", Count = rnd.Next(100), Sum = rnd.Next (100)}, 
                new TheItem () { Name = "Item 9", Count = rnd.Next(100), Sum = rnd.Next (100)}, 
            });

            CountSumSwitch = false;
        }

        public class TheItem
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Count { get; set; }
            public int Sum { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

And put this code in the MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!-- This binding needs to point to some global propery that you'll change to switch views.-->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CountSumSwitch}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="View">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Count" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Count}" />
                            </GridView>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CountSumSwitch}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="View">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Sum" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Sum}" />
                            </GridView>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CountSumSwitch}"/>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ITems}" Margin="0,83,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: that what i was looking but a little modified.. DataTrigger is key to me.. thanks, i ll try

Answer (score 1):

Implement different [ItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx)s for your listviews and switch them according to your purposes.